# Copy from clipboard using Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, clipboard

I'm trying to take a string from the Windows clipboard and paste it into a listbox in a Tkinter GUI. It works great until trying to copy a image.

```
clipboardData = root.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
listbox.insert(0, clipboardData)
```

I have tried to use Tkinter, pyperclip and clipboard. How can I avoid non-text content?

Comment: At the simplest, why not `try:` the `listbox.insert` and handle any error with `except WhateverError:`? See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: try:
        clipboardData = clipboard.get()   # root.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
except:
        print "Can't copy images"

still crashes...

Comment: Did you try putting the `insert` inside the `try`?

Comment: my mistake! the try-except solution works!
there is another solution?

Comment: How many solutions do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Tkinter`, I would use a `try..except` block to `insert` the clipboard data where it exists and ignore it where it doesn't (or, optionally, add some default value). This doesn't specifically revoke any image-type clipboard contents, but it *will* reject anything that isn't in `myTkObject.clipboard_get()`'s expected format. That's a string by default, though you can change it with the function's `type` keyword argument.

Here's an example that builds on Nodak and jonrsharpe's answer and comments:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
myTkObject = Tk()
try:
    listbox.insert(0, myTkObject.clipboard_get())
except Tkinter.TclError:
    pass  # Instead of do-nothing, you can insert some default value if you like.
```